# Using R to Compute Combinations with Repetition

Tags: r, combinations

I have one column with 13,000 elements. The elements are $ totals and I need to see every possible combination, with repetition, of up to 3 combinations in total. The combinations are just the sum of the $ amounts. How would I go about doing this and would this be way too large of a combination with repetition problem in R?

Comment: 13,000 choose 3 is 366,082,171,000. Assuming you're using doubles (64 bits each) for the sums, the memory requirement for just the results vector is over 2.9 TB. This is only the results vector and doesn't include anything like  the matrix of indices you could use to get the combinations to sum together. You likely need to simplify the problem or find ways to put constraints on it to actually do what you want to do. What is the end goal here? Why do you want ALL combinations?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was given a list of scenarios for a total $ amount. Having calculated the potential $ amounts from each scenario in Excel, there are 13,000 potential totals. The raw data I was given has nothing besides an actual $ total amount and I was tasked with seeing if these actuals can be derived from a combination of these 13,000 potential outcomes. I was told not to worry about there being false-positives at the moment, only to see if there is a match.

Comment: What's the typical range of this target matches and the typical range of 13,000 dollar amounts? I can put together a rough function to show you how to constrain the problem a bit.